# Specifc Case of Dependent Uniform Discrete RVs

Tags: probability

I am having a bit of issue understanding the following because I am unsure how to represent the variables

Let X be a RV that is uniformly chosen from $\{1,2,3\}$ and Y a RV uniformly chosen from $\{1,..,x\}$

What is the joint pmf, $E(Y|X)$, and $E(Y)$?

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Start by finding the pmf $p_X$ of $X$ and the conditional pmf $p_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x)$ of $Y$ given $X$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the correct way to represent this situation is to say that $X$ is a random variable uniformly chosen from $\{ 1,2,3\}$, and $Y$ is a random variable such that, *given* $X$, $Y$ is uniformly chosen on $\{ 1,2,\dots,X\}$. One might say that $Y\mid X=x$ is uniformly chosen from $\{ 1,2,\dots,x\}$ for $x=1,2,3$.

It is then easy to find $E(Y\mid X=x)$; for any $x=1,2,3$ we have
$$
E(Y\mid X=x)=\sum_{y=1}^x y\cdot P(Y=y\mid X=x)=\sum_{y=1}^x \frac{y}{x}=\frac{x+1}{2},
$$
so $E(Y\mid X)=(X+1)/2$. We then find by the law of total expectation:
$$
EY=E(E(Y\mid X))=\frac{EX+1}{2}=\frac{3}{2}.
$$
Lastly we need the joint PMF. We have
$$
P(X=x,Y=y)=P(Y=y\mid X=x)P(X=x).
$$
Plugging in the different values for $x$ and $y$, I am sure you can find the joint PMF.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Does this mean that for example, writing a table of values would be sufficient for representing this joint pmf? I do understand the continuous case where there is an actual function and you can use $f(x,y) = f_{x|y}(x|y)f_y(y)$, but was confused for this particular example.

Comment: Since the PMF is a function, say $\{ 1,2,3\}^2\to [0,1]$, it only takes finitely many values, so it can be represented completely by a table. So yes, a table in this case is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks! your answer was very clear.

Answer (score 0):

A random variable (RV) is a variable whose value is determined by the outcome of a random event. In the given scenario, $X$ is a RV that is uniformly chosen from $\{1, 2, 3\}$ and $Y$ is a RV that is uniformly chosen from $\{1, ..., x\}$.

The joint probability mass function (pmf) of $X$ and $Y$, denoted by $p(X, Y)$, is a function that gives the probability of $X$ and $Y$ taking on specific values. To find the joint pmf, you need to find the probability of $X$ taking on each of the values in $\{1, 2, 3\}$ and $Y$ taking on each of the values in $\{1, ..., x\}$ and multiply the probabilities together.

The expected value of $Y$ given $X$, denoted by $E(Y|X)$, is the average value of $Y$ given that $X$ takes on a specific value. To find $E(Y|X)$, you need to compute the conditional probability of $Y$ given $X$, which is given by $p(Y = y|X = x) = p(X = x, Y = y) / p(X = x)$.

The expected value of $Y$, denoted by $E(Y)$, is the average value of $Y$ over all possible values of $X$. To find $E(Y)$, you need to compute the weighted average of $Y$ given each value of $X$, where the weights are given by the probabilities of $X$ taking on those values.